# How to update a dependency to a specific git commit when using manifest mode?

Tags: vcpkg

I have a cmake project that uses vcpkg to manage its dependencies. vcpkg is used in 'manifest mode'. Meaning my dependencies are specified in the vcpkg.json that reside in the project root directory:

```
{
    "name": "myproject",
    "version-string": "1.0.0",
    "builtin-baseline": "232704deb708fc866905af170b63c1a9cb821dbc",
    "dependencies": [
        {
          "name" : "imgui",
          "default-features": true,
          "features" : ["docking-experimental"]
        },
        "magnum",
        {
          "name" : "magnum-integration",        
          "default-features": false,
          "features" : ["imgui"]
        }
    ]
}
```

The `"builtin-baseline"` field contains the git SHA-1 identifying a commit in my own privately maintained vcpkg repository.

For example, the `magnum` dependency is configured to the use latest 'baseline' version. meaning if you go to where vcpkg in installed, there is a file versions/baseline.json where the baseline is determined.

vcpkg has a (complicated and non intuitive) mechanism to pin certain dependencies to older versions. However, I could not find a structured way of how to modify the vcpkg installation so it will install a different version from a git repository. vcpkg "overlay ports" feature does not work in manifest mode.

Ideally, vcpkg would allow me to do something simple, such as:

```
    "magnum",
        {
          "git-commit" : "dagfaghsfdg",
          "name" : "magnum-integration",        
          "default-features": false,
          "features" : ["imgui"]
        }
```

So how can I configure vcpkg to use a certain git commit for a dependency (in manifest mode)?

Answer (score 7):

Currently the solution I came up with is as follows. I am not sure it is ideal.

I will demonstrate it on the "magnum" dependency.

**Step 1: Modify the relevant vcpkg/portfile.cmake**

Usually this file will contain a call to a function called `vcpkg_from_github` that refers to a git tag (`REF` parameter). Modify this parameter to refer to the desired commit.

```
vcpkg_from_github(
    OUT_SOURCE_PATH SOURCE_PATH
    REPO mosra/magnum
    REF 49bcbed2f4799e7b341975a5dde98d4ba4d288d8
    SHA512 08582553725ee63eb4c6732fa6a7d82e8e0a1fed92e0e9d82035c2aa79b0df29f1fdef521768f1ef8399cef8b4550e3a8734c3a0c4f04c40ecdb7fd6c99e1bc5
    HEAD_REF master
)
```

the SHA512 also needs to be changed. But becuase vcpkg likes to make things hard, it cannot deduce it automatically. You must to attempt a vcpkg install on the package, fail, get the actual value, and set it manually:

```
vcpkg install magnum

File does not have expected hash:

          File path: [ C:/Libraries/vcpkg/downloads/mosra-magnum-72ee390afa8dd1f9d94355595ff4dc74408977fc.tar.gz ]
      Expected hash: [ 08582553725ee63eb4c6732fa6a7d82e8e0a1fed92e0e9d82035c2aa79b0df29f1fdef521768f1ef8399cef8b4550e3a8734c3a0c4f04c40ecdb7fd6c99e1bc5 ]
        Actual hash: [ 08582553725ee63eb4c6732fa6a7d82e8e0a1fed92e0e9d82035c2aa79b0df29f1fdef521768f1ef8399cef8b4550e3a8734c3a0c4f04c40ecdb7fd6c99e1bc4 ]
```

replace the `SHA512` parameter with the value in `Actual hash`.

**Step 2: Modify the version string in vcpkg/vcpkg.json**

inside this file there is a version field. change it to something that makes sense.

```
  "name": "magnum",
  "version-string": "2022.00",
  "port-version": 0
```

I also changed the `port-version` to 0.

**Step 3: Modify the baseline**

Step 1 and 2 are enough if you wish to use non manifest mode.
But you must modify the baseline if you wish to use a manifest.

Inside versions/baseline.json, change the baseline to the new version (matches the port file).

```
"magnum": {
  "baseline": "2022.00",
  "port-version": 0
},
```

**Step 4: register the new version**

Inside the versions directory, there are directories in alphabetical order with files listing available versions for each library. for example magnum.json:

```
  "versions": [
    {
      "git-tree": "39331fa0e35e058c25f2ee188ca816343111c232",
      "version-string": "2022.00",
      "port-version": 0
    },
    ...
```

So you need to add a new version entry.
Now the "git-tree" field is **not** a git commit. it is a git object-id.
in order to get it, you need to first commit all the current changes you made to the vcpkg directory, and the do:

```
git rev-parse HEAD:ports/magnum
```

copy the output to the git-tree field.

**Step 5: repeat this for other dependencies of the dependency you changed**

In my case, magnum is dependent on "corrade" library so I had to make the same changes there.

**Step 6: change builtin-baseline**

commit all your changes to the vcpkg repository, modify your manifest file (vcpkg.json) `builtin-baseline` field to refer to the latest commit in your vcpkg repo.